# Prove that $\iota(Y):=\operatorname{ext}(X\setminus Y)$ is an interior operator?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, alternative-proof

So given a set $X$ in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3528145/736008) question I ask to show that if $\iota$ is a function from $\mathcal P(X)$ to $\mathcal P(X)$ such that

1. $\iota(X)=X$
2. $\iota(Y)\subseteq Y$ for any $Y\in\mathcal P(X)$
3. $\iota\big(\iota(Y)\big)=\iota(Y)$ for any $Y\in\mathcal P(X)$
4. $\iota(Y_1\cap Y_2)=\iota(Y_1)\cap\iota(Y_2)$ for any $Y_1,Y_2\in\mathcal P(X)$

then the collection
$$
\mathcal T:=\big\{Y\in\mathcal P(X):Y=\iota(Y)\big\}
$$
is a topology on $X$ such that
$$
\iota(Y)=\operatorname{int}Y
$$

Analogous issue is  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3545824/736008) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3533162/736008) taken on for the derived operator and boundary operator so that I ask to me if it is possible to do an analogous thing for exterior operator so that given a function $\eta$ from $\mathcal P(X)$ to $\mathcal P(X)$ such that

1. $\eta(\emptyset)=X$
2. $\eta(Y)\subseteq X\setminus Y$ for any $Y\in \mathcal P(X)$
3. $\eta(X\setminus Y)\subseteq\eta\big(\eta(Y)\big)$ for any $Y\in\mathcal P(X)$
4. $\eta(Y_1\cup Y_2)=\eta(Y_1)\cap\eta(Y_2)$ for any $Y_1,Y_2\in\mathcal P(X)$

I tried to show that the collection
$$
\mathcal T:=\big\{Y\in\mathcal P(X):Y=\eta(X\setminus Y)\big\}
$$
is a topology on $X$.

- So first of all by the identity $1$ we observe that
  $$
  X=\eta(\emptyset)=\eta(X\setminus X)
  $$
  which means that $X$ lies in $\mathcal T$. Now by the inclusion $2$ we observe that
  $$
  \eta(X)\subseteq X\setminus X=\emptyset
  $$
  so that we conclude that $$\eta (X)=\emptyset$$ So by the last identity we observe that $$\emptyset=\eta(X)=\eta(X\setminus\emptyset)$$ which means that $\emptyset$ lies in $\mathcal T$.
- Therefore if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are two element of $\mathcal T$ then by the identity $4$ we observe that
  $$
  A_1\cap A_2=\eta(X\setminus A_1)\cap\eta(X\setminus A_2)=\eta\big((X\setminus A_1)\cup(X\setminus A_2)\big)=\eta\big(X\setminus(A_1\cap A_2)\big)
  $$
  which means that $A_1\cap A_2$ lies in $\mathcal T$.
- Now we observe that if $Y_1,Y_2\in\mathcal P(X)$ are such that
  $$
  Y_1\subseteq Y_2
  $$
  then by the identity $4$ we observe that
  $$
  \eta(Y_2)=\eta(Y_1\cup Y_2)=\eta(Y_1)\cap\eta(Y_2)\subseteq\eta(Y_1)
  $$So we conclude that if $\mathcal A$ is a subcollection of $\mathcal T$ then for any $A_0\in\mathcal A$ the inclusion
  $$
  A_0=\eta(X\setminus A_0)\subseteq\eta\Biggl(\bigcap_{A\in\mathcal A}X\setminus A\Biggl)=\eta\Biggl(X\setminus\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A}A\Biggl)
  $$
  holds and so this implies that
  $$
  \bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A}A\subseteq\eta\Biggl(X\setminus\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A}A\Biggl)
  $$
  However by the identity $2$ also the inclusion
  $$
  \eta\Biggl(X\setminus\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A}A\Biggl)=X\setminus\Biggl(X\setminus\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A}A\Biggl)=\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A}A
  $$
  holds. So we finally conclude that
  $$
  \bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A}A=\eta\Biggl(X\setminus\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A}A\Biggl)
  $$
  which means that $\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A}A$ lies in $\mathcal T$.

So we conclude that $\mathcal T$ is a topology on $X$ but unfortunately I was not able to prove that the identity
$$
\eta(Y)=\operatorname{ext}Y
$$
holds for any $Y\in\mathcal P(X)$ so that I observe that if the position
$$
\tilde\iota(Y):=\eta(X\setminus Y)
$$
would define a interior operator as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3528145/736008) defined then the identity
$$
\operatorname{ext}Y=\operatorname{int}(X\setminus Y)=\tilde\iota(X\setminus Y)=\eta\big(X\setminus(X\setminus Y)\big)=\eta(Y)
$$
would be trivially true so that I tried to show that $\tilde\iota$ is an interior operator.

So first of all we observe that
$$
\tilde\iota(X)=\eta(X\setminus X)=\eta(\emptyset)=X
$$
so that the identity $1$ holds; then we observe that
$$
\tilde\iota(Y)=\eta(X\setminus Y)\subseteq X\setminus(X\setminus Y)=Y
$$
so that the inclusion $2$ holds; moreover we observe that for any $Y_1,Y_2\in\mathcal P(X)$ the idenity
$$
\tilde\iota(Y_1\cap Y_2)=\eta\big(X\setminus(Y_1\cap Y_2)\big)=\eta\big((X\setminus Y_1)\cap(X\setminus Y_2)\big)=\\
\eta(X\setminus Y_1)\cap\eta(X\setminus Y_2)=\tilde\iota(Y_1)\cap\tilde\iota(Y_2)
$$
holds so that the identity $4$ holds for $\eta$. Finally we observe that for any $Y\in\mathcal P(X)$ the inlcusion
$$
\tilde\iota\big(\tilde\iota(Y)\big)=\eta\big(X\setminus\tilde\iota(Y)\big)\subseteq X\setminus\big(X\setminus\tilde\iota(Y)\big)=\tilde\iota(Y)
$$
holds so that the identity
$$
\tilde\iota\big(\tilde\iota(Y)\big)=Y
$$
would follow by showing that
$$
\tilde\iota(Y)\subseteq\tilde\iota\big(\tilde\iota(Y)\big)
$$
but unfortunately I was not able to do it so that I thought to put a specific question: as you can see I never use the inclusion
$$
\eta(X\setminus Y)\subseteq\eta\big(\eta(Y)\big)
$$
so that I argue that I have to use it or rather I have to substitute it with another inclusion. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: I haven't tried looking through this (simply don't have time now, or in the near future), but possibly the references in my answer to [definitionS of a topological space (reference)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2254849/13130) and my 3-part answer to  [General topological space with closure operation as in Russian translation of Hausdorff's 1914 and 1927 Mengenlehre](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342205/15780) will be of use and/or interest to you.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Oh, thanks for the reference: I will read it. Anyway it seem to me that if I substitute the inclusion $$\eta(X\setminus Y)\subseteq\eta\big(\eta(Y)\big)$$ with the identity $$\eta(Y)=\eta\big(X\setminus\eta(Y)\big)$$ then the statement follows but unfortunately this do not implies that the statement cannot follow by the above inclusion.

Comment: So the question is: what properties characterizes effectively the exterior of a set?

Comment: Did you look at the paper by Miron Zarycki that I cited? I don't know if your use of the term "exterior" is the same as his use of the word "exterior", but Zarycki's paper should certainly be looked over I think.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Oh, thanks for the nice reference!!! Reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_Situs_(paper)) wiki article I presume that Zarycki use the word "exterior" just as I used it: indeed it seem that he want make a topology using exterior or boundary or closure sets and not only directely open (and so interior!) sets; moreover it seem that $IV_e$ point it is just the identity $$\eta(Y)=\eta\big(X\setminus\eta(Y)\big)$$ so that what I observed above would be correct: what can you say about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that the inclusion
$$
\eta(X\setminus Y)\subseteq\eta\big(\eta(Y)\big)
$$
for any $Y\in\mathcal P(X)$ does not works: indeed, although I did not find any couterexample, in [this](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm9/fm912.pdf) paper (mentioned into the comments by Dave L. Renfro) Miron Zarycki says that an exterior operator $\eta$ must be suc that
$$
\eta(Y)=\eta\big(X\setminus\eta(Y)\big)
$$
for any $Y\in\mathcal P(X)$ and in fact if the last equality holds then
$$
\tilde\iota\big(\tilde\iota(Y)\big)=\tilde\iota\big(\eta(X\setminus Y)\big)=\eta\big(X\setminus\eta(X\setminus Y)\big)=\eta(X\setminus Y)=\tilde\iota(Y)
$$
for any $Y\in\mathcal P(X)$ so that in this case effectively $\tilde\iota$ is an interior operator.